# Orbitals, shapes and wave function relation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, probability, orbitals

Are the shapes of orbitals like $s$ which is sphere due to wave function or due to square of the wave function?

Comment: http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Chemical/eleorb.html

Answer (score 2):

The typical pictures of the orbitals show a thresholded square of the wavefunction. This is because the square of the wavefunction gives the probability density, and the wavefunction itself is complex(which is harder to plot).

Comment: so it is right to say that the ψ^2 and not ψ is the space where electrons can be found ?

Comment: @adosar Kind of. Technically $|\psi|^2$ extends past what typical diagrams show. That's why I used the word "thresholded", to show the most likely regions.